# How to do a MongoDB 6 single node replicaset with Docker compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

On my local Mac M1 PRO, I use for several month now a Docker compose to mount a single node replicaset based on MongoDB 5.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5
    command: --replSet rs0
    ports:
      - '28017:27017'
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo localhost:27017/admin --quiet
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5

  mongo-init:
    image: mongo:5
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: >
      mongo --host mongodb:27017 --eval
      '
      rs.initiate( {
        _id : "rs0",
        members: [
          { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27017" }
        ]
      })
      '
```

It works well and I have a simple MongoDB 5 replicaset. Now, I want the same thing with MongoDB 6. So, I modify the image from mongodb:5 to mongodb:6 but the replicaset didn't mount.

I have this error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-04-14T08:52:52.326+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-", "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24600}}
```

I don't need TLS or encryption fancy feature.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mongo6 docker container has changed some internals, here is a working version for me
Port differences arent relevant except for setting your correct ones in the commands/healthchecks.

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo:6
    command: [--replSet, my-replica-set, --bind_ip_all, --port, "30001"]
    ports:
      - 30001:30001
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(mongosh --port 30001 --quiet --eval "try {rs.initiate({_id:'my-replica-set',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongo:30001\"}]})} catch(e) {rs.status().ok}") -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, incredible hard to find a working configuration.

Comment: Just wondering, do you need to use a different port?

Comment: Thank you! I'd point out to anyone viewing this and upgrading from 5.0 to 6.0, if you connected with mongo it needs to be mongosh

Answer (score 3):

I had an additional requirement, namely that I wanted to have another user for a different database be initialized on that single node. MongoDB then requires a keyfile for all nodes in the replica set even though no other is there. With the help of this Github [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/475) I got the following setup.

Create a keyfile in your current directory

```
openssl rand -base64 756 > keyfile
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
---
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: mongo 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin 
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
          cp /keyfile /mongo_keyfile
          chmod 400 /mongo_keyfile
          chown 999:999 /mongo_keyfile
          exec docker-entrypoint.sh $$@
    command: "mongod --bind_ip_all --replSet rs0 --keyFile /mongo_keyfile"
    volumes:
      - ./keyfile:/keyfile

  mongo-setup:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: mongo_setup
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    restart: on-failure
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "/setup_mongo.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./setup_mongo.sh:/setup_mongo.sh
```

Your MongoDB will run on a container with hostname mongo, it's entrypoint needs some tricks to get the `keyfile` working, the second container `mongo_setup`, initializes then your replica set and creates the new users, with the following bash script. You maybe need to add an executable flag to the file.

setup_mongo.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash 

# TODO: This script assumes the following
# you named the container where your mongod runs 'mongo'
# you changed MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE to 'admin'
# you set MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME to 'root'
# you set MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD to 'secret'
# you set the replica set name to 'rs0' (--replSet)
until mongosh --host mongo:27017 --eval 'quit(db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2)' &>/dev/null; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done

cd /
echo '
try {
    var config = {
        "_id": "rs0", // TODO update this with your replica set name
        "version": 1,
        "members": [
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "host": "mongo:27017", // TODO rename this host
            "priority": 2
        },
        ]
    };
    rs.initiate(config, { force: true });
    rs.status();
    sleep(5000);
    // creates another user
    admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
    admin.createUser(
          {
        user: "otheradmin",
        pwd:  "othersecret", 
        roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "myowndb" },
             { role: "readWrite", db: "admin" } ,
        
        ]
          }
    );
} catch(e) {
    rs.status().ok
}
' > /config-replica.js



sleep 10
# TODO update user, password, authenticationDatabase and host accordingly
mongosh -u root -p "secret" --authenticationDatabase admin --host mongo:27017 /config-replica.js

# if the output of the container mongo_setup exited with code 0, everything is probably okay
```